# Clustering with ambigous input values

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

Imagine the following scenario:

I have two 4x100 matrices `ang1_stab` and `ang2_stab`. These contain four angles along the columns, like this:

```
195.7987   16.2722   14.4171  198.5878  199.2693...
80.2062   86.7363   89.2861   89.5454   89.3411...
68.7998  -83.8318  -80.3138   69.0636  -96.4913...
-5.3262  -23.3030  -20.6823  -18.9915  -16.7224...

95.3450  183.8212  171.0686  151.8887  177.9041...
21.4780   27.2389   23.4016   27.6631   17.2893...
-13.2767 -103.5548 -115.0615   39.6790 -112.3568...
-5.3262  -23.3030  -20.6823  -18.9915  -16.7224...
```

The fourth angle is always the same for both matrices, so it can be neglected.

The problem: some of the columns of `ang1_stab` and `ang2_stab` are swapped, so I need to find the columns that would fit better into the other matrix and then swap the respective columns.

The complication: The calculation of the given angles is ambigous and multiples of 90° might have been added/subtracted, e.g. the angle 16° should be considered closer to 195° than to 95°.

What I have tried so far:

```
fp1 = []; % define clusters
fp2 = []; 
for j = 1:size(ang1_stab,2) % loop over all columns
    tmp1 = ang1_stab(:,j); % temporary columns
    tmp2 = ang2_stab(:,j);

    if j == 1 % assign first cluster center
        fp1 = [fp1, tmp1];
        fp2 = [fp2, tmp2];
    else
        mns1 = median(fp1(1:3,:),2); % calculate cluster centers
        mns2 = median(fp2(1:3,:),2);

        % calculate distances to cluster centers
        dif11 = sum(abs((mns1-tmp1(1:3))-round((mns1-mp1(1:3))/90)*90)); 
        dif12 = sum(abs((mns1-tmp2(1:3))-round((mns1-tmp2(1:3))/90)*90));
        dif21 = sum(abs((mns2-tmp1(1:3))-round((mns2-tmp1(1:3))/90)*90));
        dif22 = sum(abs((mns2-tmp2(1:3))-round((mns2-tmp2(1:3))/90)*90));

        if min([dif11,dif21])<min([dif12,dif22]) % assign to cluster
            if dif11<dif21
                fp1 = [fp1,tmp1];
                fp2 = [fp2,tmp2];

            else
                fp1 = [fp1,tmp2];
                fp2 = [fp2,tmp1];
            end
        else
            if dif12<dif22
                fp1 = [fp1,tmp2];
                fp2 = [fp2,tmp1];

            else
                fp1 = [fp1,tmp1];
                fp2 = [fp2,tmp2];
            end
        end


    end
end
```

However:

1. This appraoch seems overly complicated and I was wondering if I can somehow replace it with an appropriate algorithm, e.g. kmeans. However, I don't know how to account for the ambiguity in the angles in that case.
2. The code is working, but the clustering does currently still throw points in the wrong cluster. I just cannot find why.

I would appreciate it, if someone could tell me how to adopt this to work with built-in routines like `kmeans` or so.

Edit:
A small toy example:
This could be the output that I am getting:

```
ang1_stab = [30 10 80 100; 28 15 90 95; 152 93 180 102]; 
ang2_stab = [150 90 3 100; 145 92 5 95; 32 10 82 102];
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
fp1 = [30 10 80 100; 28 15 90 95; 32 10 82 102]; 
fp2 = [150 90 3 100; 145 92 5 95;  152 93 180 102];
```

Note that the last columns have been swapped.
Also note that the third element in the last column of fp2 is approximately the mean of the other elements in that row, but 180° higher. I still need to be able to identify this is the right cluster.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. Could you give a couple of sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: I edited a toy example